# MongoDB with 1B documents, what is most optimum filter to return recently updated documents

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a production mongo database of over 1B documents in a single collection sharded on _id across multiple servers.  I'm trying to replicate recently updated records from this collection into Red Shift.

**Shard keys:**

db.sample_collection.ensureIndex({_id: "hashed"})

sh.shardCollection("sample_collection.sample_object", {_id: "hashed"})

**Example 'sample_object' Document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("527a6c9226d6b7770ab05345"),
    "p": ISODate("2013-10-27T14:30:18.000Z"),
    "a" : {
        "ln" : "Doe",
        "id" : NumberLong(3),
        "fn" : "John",
    },
    "co" : {
        "ct" : 2,
        "it" : [
                {'t': 'loreum', 'u' : NumberLong(300), 'd': ISODate("2013-10-28T14:30:18.000Z")},
                {'t': 'loreum', 'u' : NumberLong(400), 'd': ISODate("2013-10-29T14:30:18.000Z")},
                ..]
    },
    "li" : {
        "ct" : 2,
        "it" : [
                {'u' : NumberLong(500), 'd': ISODate("2013-10-30T14:30:18.000Z")},
                {'u' : NumberLong(501), 'd': ISODate("2013-10-29T14:30:18.000Z")},
                ..]
    },

}
```

**Option #1:**

I'm in the process of analyzing this data and I need to query for documents that were "updated" between a period.
i.e., I want to return all the objects that have been p (published) or an li.it (item) or co.it (item) added between '2014-07-01' and '2014-07-03'.

What would be the most performant way of doing this?

**Option #2:**

Another option that I'm evaluating is whether I want to add an 'u' property with an updated date to account for when the document was updated 
(ie., li or co item added)

If I make the change to the process to ensure new documents have this property, how would I iterate through existing documents and add this retroactively?

Would filtering on 'u' be more performant that Option 1?  I'm looking at this option as using COPY FROM JSON from a mongoexport

Comment: You kind of threw this all away by choosing to "Hash" your shard key. Though the danger here is creating "hotspots" by working with a created date or even an updated date on write operations, you seem to want this on read operations. The question is, which is most important to you? Any query outside of the shard key is a "scatter gather" operation.

Comment: could you do a step-wise scatter gather that would not effect overall server performance?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option #1 (multiple dates)

There isn't a good option to index this, as it looks like you would ideally want a compound index that includes `p` (date) plus two date arrays (`lt.it` and `co.it`). A compound index can only include at most [one array field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#interactions-between-compound-and-multikey-indexes). Even if you *could* do this, the index would be very large given the suggested number of dates and the query would involve checking multiple fields to infer the last updated date.

#### Option #2 (single updated date)

Adding an indexed `u` (latest updated date) is definitely a better approach to allow a simple and performant query.

> If I make the change to the process to ensure new documents have this property, how would I iterate through existing documents and add this retroactively?

You can use the [`$exists` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to find documents that do not have this field set yet.

#### Caveat on hashed shard key

To elaborate on Neil's comment: a hashed shard key gives you good write distribution at the expense of being able to do range queries (all queries become scatter-gather). If your common queries are range-based on date (and you are concerned about performance) then you could possibly [chose a more appropriate shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) to support those queries. However, since shard keys are [immutable](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#considerations) and you want to query on an "updated" date, it doesn't sound like a change of shard key will help your use case.